# How to add a eCharts DataZoom to a graph

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

I have implemented an eCharts graph. See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qgf4c2jy/3/

```
    option = {
        title: {
            text: 'Basic Graph'
        },
        tooltip: {},
        animationDurationUpdate: 1500,
        animationEasingUpdate: 'quinticInOut',
        series: [
            {
                type: 'graph',
                layout: 'none',
                symbolSize: 50,
                roam: true,
                label: {
                    show: true
                },
                edgeSymbol: ['circle', 'arrow'],
                edgeSymbolSize: [4, 10],
                edgeLabel: {
                    fontSize: 20
                },
                data: [
                    {
                        name: 'A',
                        x: 300,
                        y: 300
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'B',
                        x: 800,
                        y: 300
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'C',
                        x: 550,
                        y: 100
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'D',
                        x: 550,
                        y: 500
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'E',
                        x: 1000,
                        y: 300
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'F',
                        x: 1200,
                        y: 300
                    }
                ],
                // links: [],
                links: [
                    {
                        source: 'A',
                        target: 'C'
                    },
                    {
                        source: 'B',
                        target: 'C'
                    },
                    {
                        source: 'B',
                        target: 'D'
                    },
                    {
                        source: 'A',
                        target: 'D'
                    },
                    {
                        source: 'B',
                        target: 'E'
                    },
                    {
                        source: 'E',
                        target: 'F'
                    }
                ],
                lineStyle: {
                    opacity: 0.9,
                    width: 2,
                    curveness: 0
                }
            }
        ]
    };
```

The resulting graph basically looks like this:

[image]

The x position of each node corresponds to the time axis. Thus, in this example graph, "E" happens before "F" and after "B".

How can I extend this graph with a DataZoom on the xAxis like in this example? https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-error-scatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding the X/Y data as an array under the property `value` in the `data` object seems to work for [coordinateSystem](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-graph.coordinateSystem) `cartesian2d`.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graph-grid&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDGBvGMBAWwFMAuGAcgEEqAaGANwQBsBXCzAZgAZfGfXgF0YAX3o58hElyoAhBszadKGABz9B_URKkEiZSlQDCSlhy4YArNYEwAjDvGTcB2cYAi5lVdv27ERd9GSNqAFEfSzUnLRghXVdpQzkAMSjVTAcAJjiE8SxhAG4sLFBIWFYASzAAawg0TBCIEHYAJ2A5OkZkNoBzUihjM2C3GBb2zuNFHoR-weGqUekJjrkZmF6BoepvZYJVqepuzbntryW9McP1pS2FiMukg9a140jZ-Z2qdILi0pAAAcoFVwI08FIQVBWFwIbhcFBSAAPb7yBAQKrAGAAcTaCEBAAsqFIrpsQCBWCDAZQ8KSkTQkVUIDTiAgkZQHAAWfikgCeDKZLLZlAAbDykohkAAtcnEGlQXmAuQQapwUhtKikiDqqqkZlNeH4KSGhVK4x9PGEhjG-GgEBtOA1JCkADKvOgpDl1GAc0RGIQYGycGthtwrAQvNa3zA4FIIdDEF5xAARhSXVUAF5cOxJQ1tEAkShQNqcXPw8PJ0isGk2w0QAkgADuRZLpFry0NpDgAzdKYpaiowCqHRhSioc3zjaowjLuC7PaTqdY6azak5jCcM_b89IABkEJXq0bQ_CAGbgKArri5dukw2ShCUB-zmDVOr6t_1F9v10KmE1k9cCBBAhwVSheAAOgAThfXBGyqOAoAJShslgmBgHaJhSDAPV9V4W8bTEKRhCwMQiiAA):

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'A', value: [300, 300] },
  { name: 'B', value: [800, 300] },
  { name: 'C', value: [550, 100] },
  { name: 'D', value: [550, 500] },
  { name: 'E', value: [1000, 300] },
  { name: 'F', value: [1200, 300] }
];

const links = [
  { source: 'A', target: 'C' },
  { source: 'B', target: 'C' },
  { source: 'B', target: 'D' },
  { source: 'A', target: 'D' },
  { source: 'B', target: 'E' },
  { source: 'E', target: 'F' }
];

option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Basic Graph'
  },
  tooltip: {},
  xAxis: {max: 1400},
  yAxis: {max: 600},
  dataZoom: {type: 'slider'},
  series: [
    {
      type: 'graph',
      coordinateSystem: 'cartesian2d',
      layout: 'none',
      symbolSize: 50,
      roam: true,
      label: {
        show: true
      },
      edgeSymbol: ['circle', 'arrow'],
      edgeSymbolSize: [4, 10],
      edgeLabel: {
        fontSize: 20
      },
      data: data,
      links: links,
      lineStyle: {
        opacity: 0.9,
        width: 2,
        curveness: 0
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

echarts gives one config key say `coordinateSystem`. for more info:[click here](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-graph.coordinateSystem)

Here, I have implemented basic example: [EXAMPLE](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graph-grid&code=MYewdgzgLgBAhgDwJYQCJynGBeGBtAcgFlwCAaGAgFQFcBTcygdToBNGCA1OgJwE8YAGRAjwAcxhUAFjQ4AxHkg4BlDCppgCAXQDcAKFCRYrDFlyIU6TADoAtnAAOACgBmG4FCTgYTpFDq2FEgAlDAA3nowMDx0UDQ8YDBEGFLWPCAarE7JUKk8cGCsILZOoQBUMACMAAy1MBW-MADUVcHB-gC-7Qbg0DAANkhgANYQODAmNvbObmAeXom-_oEwIeGR0bHxiRFRURAZPMB0AFyrZBtRmDxisWdIzVUbHZ3dgyMQ1g4gzt0_nt5cLsYJ4oP1Tus9iC6AgoGcCABxfIOKQwbwAYTgPH8ECQBQIzwuVxE_U8DjOYQ6RJgCAAgsgIBTLiC-A4IQRgBg6GIQPxyMyAEYZQpYvgIxxnFxwfoQOjUqKTOBnCxoUzymDMgD0mpgADkAPJUACiZz4GRgnMSstgUB49GsIJAMAgUhAAHd4AytTqXe6TlKZXRCRs-PSUEyoVBWeyAG7S-j8qHevWGk0wM00C0FZ2xEF2ugOqBO30elXJkuS6WyqLBhWmABaIlsZzwzOBkej8Igg1YvAJUKpbeZV07lCGuN7_b2HQ2WmpssUdEZ-CHUJHbPhYmRUkTa_6cAzcMoYHADHVUVAvNYQy5yj40AC8M52KXeLAACZ2OfnXxbEL-soSAAF4QgALNU377gKdD9BGa77K6bpnLa9DDjAg7wWwtx3n-ICwfgHJIEc4IcFi6Ruto35YXQOH_oBIEtqBFA1HOaGKmciqQUMoxnO8oxcWANFRuCcHwaA_S8vCADE74uKBACs8mgVOA7MjOURaHoLxAA)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help. However, I'm not sure if the answer will help me as I have a graph with hundreds of nodes and these nodes are all at specific X/Y positions (as in the fiddle example I posted).

Comment: @itsame69, i have given similar example to the one provided above, but with the x and y axis as  hidden. Please refer to the updated example link.